# (Swift 4.1): Using a Protocol in Its Associated Type's Constraints

Tags: swift

While going through the chapter on Generics in the latest Swift 4.1 official documentation, I came across this example, and I am stuck now:

```
extension Stack: SuffixableContainer {
    func suffix(_ size: Int) -> Stack {
        var result = Stack()
        for index in (count-size)..<count {
            result.append(self[index])
        }
        return result
    }
    // Inferred that Suffix is Stack.
}
```

*The example doesn't tell me which version of the 'Stack' structure its using for the extension.* There are more than two versions of 'Stack' and I have tried using all of them but can't seem to make it work. And I'm using XCode 9.3 Beta as suggested.

The above example makes use of the following:

```
protocol Container {
    associatedtype Item: Equatable
    mutating func append(_ item: Item)
    var count: Int { get }
    subscript(i: Int) -> Item { get }
}

protocol SuffixableContainer: Container {
    associatedtype Suffix: SuffixableContainer where Suffix.Item == Item
    func suffix(_ size: Int) -> Suffix
}
```

Stack Versions:

```
//Version 1:
struct Stack<Element> {
    var items = [Element]()
    mutating func push(_ item: Element) {
        items.append(item)
    }
    mutating func pop() -> Element {
        return items.removeLast()
    }
}

extension Stack {
    var topItem: Element? {
        return items.isEmpty ? nil : items[items.count - 1]
    }
}


//Version 2:
struct Stack<Element>: Container {
    // original Stack<Element> implementation
    var items = [Element]()
    mutating func push(_ item: Element) {
        items.append(item)
    }
    mutating func pop() -> Element {
        return items.removeLast()
    }
    // conformance to the Container protocol
    mutating func append(_ item: Element) {
        self.push(item)
    }
    var count: Int {
        return items.count
    }
    subscript(i: Int) -> Element {
        return items[i]
    }
}
```

Using either version gives me conformance errors like "Stack does not conform to Container", etc.

How do I make the example work? Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the example in this order and it worked. Yay!!!

Edit: I also removed the constraint, Equatable, from Container.

```
protocol Container {
    associatedtype Item
    mutating func append(_ item: Item)
    var count: Int { get }
    subscript(i: Int) -> Item { get }
}


struct Stack<Element>: Container {
    // original Stack<Element> implementation
    var items = [Element]()
    mutating func push(_ item: Element) {
        items.append(item)
    }
    mutating func pop() -> Element {
        return items.removeLast()
    }
    // conformance to the Container protocol
    mutating func append(_ item: Element) {
        self.push(item)
    }
    var count: Int {
        return items.count
    }
    subscript(i: Int) -> Element {
        return items[i]
    }
}


//Using a Protocol in Its Associated Type's Constraints

protocol SuffixableContainer: Container {
    associatedtype Suffix: SuffixableContainer where Suffix.Item == Item

    func suffix(_ size: Int) -> Suffix //returns a given number of elements
    //from the end of the container, storing them in an instance of the Suffix type
}

extension Stack: SuffixableContainer {
    func suffix(_ size: Int) -> Stack {
        var result = Stack()
        for index in (count-size)..<count {
            result.append(self[index])
        }
        return result
    }
    // Inferred that Suffix is Stack.
}


var stackOfInts = Stack<Int>()
stackOfInts.append(10)
stackOfInts.append(20)
stackOfInts.append(30)
let suffix = stackOfInts.suffix(2)
print(suffix)
```

Comment: If rearranging the protocol and struct declaration order changes the result (i.e. whether it compiles or not), that's a bug in Swift and we should be reporting it.

Comment: You've removed the constraint `: Equatable` from the `Item` associated type in the protocol, that was probably your issue, not the order ;)

Comment: Hamish, yes I did. I think you're correct. Maybe I should mention that in the answer.